# Is polystyrene safe to use as a wall of a grow box?

Tags: insulation, plastic, heat, protection

I'm building a small 40x40x40 cm grow box that will be used mainly for seeds germination.
When operating, it will be completely sealed.

My question is: Is it safe to use polystyrene boards as direct insulation of the box? Because its main purpose is seeds germination, I need to maintain a stable temperature, for example, 30°C (86°F). To heat up the box, I'll use a heater made from a power resistor. I'm not sure yet what temperature of the power resistor will be at this moment; anyway, I'm wondering how safe is it? Or else, what could I do to make the polystyrene less flammable, maybe coat it with paint color?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. There's no way we could tell without more details, and even then this is probably off-topic for Home Improvement. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Hi, I'm sorry if I misunderstood the DIY abbreviation. I thought this could be the right place with the right community to answer such a question. By the way, what details are you missing, so I can improve the question next time? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, the "DIY" prefix on the URL is a misleading thing. On the details, a diagram showing the layout, plus an idea of the resistor's power dissipation, might help an answerer, but even then it's almost certainly off-topic. (Sorry.)

Comment: Might be better on https://gardening.stackexchange.com/ but unfortunately the "recommend another site" option doesn't let us officially do that.

Comment: Use a food safe material on the inside of the box and put the insulation on the outside.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Thank you for the feedback! I'll improve the question and ask in a more appropriate forum.

Comment: @AlaskaMan What do you mean by food-safe material?

Comment: I thought maybe the seeds were for edible plants.  No matter the plant you want something that will not leach chemicals into the soil. Research, food safe garden planters.

Comment: Even a soldering iron will not ignite polystyrene; you're fine.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks. that's what I wanted to hear!

Answer (score 1):

30 degrees is fine, otherwise you'd be seeing melted polystyrene containers everywhere, especially around coffee machines..
The sheets can soak up water so it will need water proofing.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm more concerned about the temperature of the heating element. I'll use heat sink and a PC fan, so I guess I'm fine then!